# SQLManagementStudio - Available databases combo box in menu - can't find it in Tools/Customize

Tags: gui, sql-server, ide

GUI customisation question: In MS SQLServer Management studio there is a combo box with the databases available at the server.  I want to copy it to the menu row; but I can't find the control in the Tools/Customize dialogue.

Longer explanation:
One can customise the toolboxes through the menu Tools/Customize.
I want to have a combo box containing the Available databases in the menu.  I know it exists since I can find it in the SQL Editor toolbar.  But I can't find it in the Customize toolbox.  Then I need to copy it to the menu toolbar but that I know how to do.

Comment: Corresponds to exactly what I was looking to do as well. Was able to do this in SSMS 2008. But not in SSMS 2014. Well worded, since I couldn't find any other match to the issue in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The customize functionality only supports adding/removing/moving button controls.  This, as a combo box, is not a button and is not supported in any location other than its default location in the SQL Editor toolbar.  The most you can do with that drop down is use the Rearrange Commands function to move it to a different position in the SQL Editor toolbar.

Comment: Dang!  Because in VS I can.  Using ManagementStudio after using Visualstudio is a bit like calling the bank - A travel 10 years back in time.

Comment: Yea, SSMS is unfortunately a pale imitation of VS.  I wish they'd put more effort into it.

Comment: Actually, in SSMS 2008, while in "Customize Toolbar" mode, you could simply drag the combo box up to the menu row, exactly as the OP requested. Seems this functionality was removed in SSMS 2014 (possibly in SSMS 2012...haven't used that one).